# GraphQL: unknown keywords when trying to query

Tags: ruby, graphql

I currently using the github/graphql-client ruby gem to try and query my GraphQL API. Here is what I have.

```
module MyAPI
  HTTP = GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new("http://myapi.com/graphql")
  Schema = GraphQL::Client.load_schema(HTTP)
  Client = GraphQL::Client.new(schema: Schema, execute: HTTP)
end

# Create the query.
CreateMeeting = MyAPI::Client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
  mutation CreateMeeting($name: String!, $meeting_id: String!){
    createMeeting(name: $name, meeting_id: $meeting_id){
      name
    }
  }
GRAPHQL

meeting = {name: 'test', meeting_id: 'm_id'}
MyAPI::Client.query(CreateMeeting, meeting)
```

This give me back the following error:

`unknown keywords: name, meeting_id`

I'm not sure what's causing this, because within createMeeting on the API name and meeting_id are defined as String arguments.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't use graphql-ruby ; it seems to me that you must name your mutation

Comment: I added a name to my mutation, still no luck.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?